# Why are my modal button images showing on top of my modal boxes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So here's the thing: A project I'm doing for film school involves making a website. I am in absolutely no way supposed to be a professional (or even a good) programmer (in fact I'm pretty bad), but I wanted to make an old school 90s/2000s styled website.


I modified some code for modal boxes from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp and it worked out fine until I needed more modal boxes, because now, when I open the modal boxes, the one which is written first in the code shows up with the backdrop and everything, but the clickable image buttons for the subsequent modal boxes show up on top of the box and its backdrop. I'm not sure what's going on. I tried putting all the code in a single `<script>` tag and all the css in one `<style>` tag too, but it did nothing. I think I just don't know what I'm doing.


Sorry for the variable, id and class names being in Portuguese, I am Brazilian and this is for Brazilian college.


PS.: I realize there are like a trillion other huge HTML, CSS and JS ***sins*** in my code (such as *all* CSS and JSS being inline), so it's understandable if you cringe or puke instantly by looking at my code. This is because I hadn't coded in years and didn't have time to relearn the real logic behind everything, and also I am using a terrible sitebuilder which barely lets me use HTML, so I had to trick the site by writing all the code inside an HTML box widget. I think you have to pay for premium to actually use different CSS and JS files. So this is all workarounds on top of workarounds on top of workarounds.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FF6842">
<style>
.container {
position: fixed;
top:150px;
}

.container2 {
  position:relative;
  right:20px;
}

.container3 {
  position:relative;
}

#intro-j {
position:fixed;
top:196px;
left:44px;
color:#ffff00;
}
  
#balao {
  position:fixed;
  top:370px;
  left:966px;
}

#bem-vindo {
  position:fixed;
  top:100px;
  left:423px;
  }
  
#logoblog {
  position:fixed;
  top:-2px;
  left:51px;
}
  
#gaiola {
  position:fixed;
  top:450px;
  left:330px;
}
#lona {
  position:fixed;
  left:248px;
  top:15px;
}
  
#counter {
  position:fixed;
  top:540px;
  left:170px;
}
  
#janela {
  position:fixed;
  top:170px;
  left:15px;
}
  
#circo-gif-j {
  position:fixed;
  top:370px;
  left:47px;
}
  
#menu {
  position:fixed;
  top:550px;
  left:44px;
  color:#00ff00;
}
  
#lc {
  color:#00ff00;
}
  
#mesabolo {
  position:fixed;
  top:540px;
  left:960px;
}
  
#bolo {
  position:fixed;
  top:470px;
  left:1018px;
}
  
#computador {
  position:fixed;
  top:394px;
  left:700px;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/0uGRDgL.png" alt="Cortinas" height="600px" width="1250px" id="bg">
  <div id="mesabolo" class="container" class="container2" class="container3">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MKP2Ezx.png" height="170px">
      <div id="janela" class="container" class="container2" class="container3">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TEFvChC.png">
   <div id="intro-j" class="container">text</div>
  <div id="circo-gif-j" class="container">
    <img src="https://www.gif.ovh/portuguese-gif/Palha%C3%A7o%20Gif/Palha%C3%A7o%20Gif%20(21).gif">
        </div>
        <div id="menu" class="container"><b><a href="cartas.php" id="lc">• Cartas</a><br>• Contato</b></div>
  </div>
    <div id="lona" class="container" class="container2">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZHX8oEe.png" height="700px">
      <div id="counter" class="container" class="container2" class="container3">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/pGkiIuH.png" height="200px" width="850px">
<div id="bem-vindo" class="container">
<img src="https://gifimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/seja-bem-vindo-gif-6.gif">
<div id="balao" class="container">
  <a href="javascript:alert('---');"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/pcJDYM7.gif" height="90px"></a>
  </div>
  
  <div id="logoblog" class="container">
    <a href=""><img src="https://i.imgur.com/CLC5YzA.gif"></a>          


    
<!--GAIOLA-->

    
    <div id="gaiola" class="container">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/zlmgazC.gif"></a>
          <style>

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ffe38a;
  height: 310px;
  margin:auto;
  left:210px;
  top:190px;
}
            
.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

#modal-text {
  color:#c83434;
}
</style>
      <div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p id="modal-text">modal text 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
      <script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("gaiola");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    modal2.style.display = "none";
  }
});
</script>
    </div>


    
<!--BOLO-->


        <div id="bolo" class="container">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/RjoYsYb.gif" height="90px"></a>
          <style>

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal2 {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content2 {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ffe38a;
  height: 350px;
  margin:auto;
  left:210px;
  top:190px;
}
            
.modal-body2 {padding: 2px 16px;}

#modal-text2 {
  color:#c83434;
}
</style>
      <div id="myModal2" class="modal2">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content2">
    <div class="modal-body2">
      <p id="modal-text2">modal text 2<br></p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
      <script>
// Get the modal
var modal2 = document.getElementById("myModal2");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn2 = document.getElementById("bolo");


// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn2.onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal2) {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
});
</script>
    </div>
    

    
<!--COMPUTADOR-->


        <div id="computador" class="container">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/s4sHQ1V.gif" height="200px"></a>
          <style>

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal3 {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content3 {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ffe38a;
  height: 350px;
  margin:auto;
  left:210px;
  top:190px;
}
            
.modal-body3 {padding: 2px 16px;}

#modal-text3 {
  color:#c83434;
}
</style>
      <div id="myModal3" class="modal3">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content3">
    <div class="modal-body3">
      <p id="modal-text3">modal text 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
      <script>
// Get the modal
var modal3 = document.getElementById("myModal3");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn3 = document.getElementById("computador");


// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn3.onclick = function() {
  modal3.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal3) {
    modal3.style.display = "none";
  }
});
</script>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if I understood what you wanted to implement. However, The cause of the problem here might be from the complexity of how everything is in one place which leaves large room for mistakes.
Please try to

1. Place all your CSS should be placed in the head section if you won't use an external file.
2. Place your JavaScript properly in the head/before end of the body tag based on what it does. if you won't use an external file.
3. You don't need to duplicate CSS more than once if the group of elements will share the same style. just use the same class across those elements.
4. The modal should be pushed down to the bottom of the page to make it easier for your to modify your HTML file.
5. In cases like this one you should use loops and arrays to minimize the repition of actions (I do understand that you are completely new to it, this is why I am trying to tell you what you can look up.)

I modified your code and applied some changes now all you need to do if you will add a new modal is add a new line to the Array with both the modal's id and its container's id.

Your full page code be found at the bottom of my answer, the following is a snippet for you to preview the code. if this not what you needed can you please explain further maybe I can help?

```js
//Array with a list of the modal id and conatiner id
var modalsArray = [
  ["modal1", "gaiola"],
  ["modal2", "bolo"],
  ["modal3", "computador"],
];
//stores the currently visible modal
var visibleModal;
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target == visibleModal) {
    visibleModal.classList.remove("visible");
    visibleModal = "";
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
  }
});

//Iterate through the modalsArray and add a click event listener
for (let modal = 0; modal < modalsArray.length; modal++) {
  document
    .getElementById(modalsArray[modal][1])
    .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      for (let mod = 0; mod < modalsArray.length; mod++) {
        if (
          e.target.offsetParent ==
          document.getElementById(modalsArray[mod][1])
        ) {
          //add the visible class to show the modal
          document
            .getElementById(modalsArray[mod][0])
            .classList.add("visible");
          //store the currently visible modal in the visible modal variable
          visibleModal = document.getElementById(modalsArray[mod][0]);
          // stops the click event from propagating up which would hide the modal again
          document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
          e.stopPropagation();
        }
      }
    });
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
}

.container2 {
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
}

.container3 {
  position: relative;
}

#intro-j {
  position: fixed;
  top: 196px;
  left: 44px;
  color: #ffff00;
}

#balao {
  position: fixed;
  top: 370px;
  left: 966px;
}

#bem-vindo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 423px;
}

#logoblog {
  position: fixed;
  top: -2px;
  left: 51px;
}

#gaiola {
  position: fixed;
  top: 450px;
  left: 330px;
}

#lona {
  position: fixed;
  left: 248px;
  top: 15px;
}

#counter {
  position: fixed;
  top: 540px;
  left: 170px;
}

#janela {
  position: fixed;
  top: 170px;
  left: 15px;
}

#circo-gif-j {
  position: fixed;
  top: 370px;
  left: 47px;
}

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 550px;
  left: 44px;
  color: #00ff00;
}

#lc {
  color: #00ff00;
}

#mesabolo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 540px;
  left: 960px;
}

#bolo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 470px;
  left: 1018px;
}

#computador {
  position: fixed;
  top: 394px;
  left: 700px;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ffe38a;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

#modal-text {
  color: #c83434;
}

.visible {
  display: block !important;
  z-index: 3;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  /* Sit on top of the page content */
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  /* Black background with opacity */
  z-index: 2;
  /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different order for other elements */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Add a pointer on hover */
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#FF6842">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0uGRDgL.png" alt="Cortinas" height="600px" width="1250px" id="bg" />
    <div id="mesabolo" class="container" class="container2" class="container3">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MKP2Ezx.png" height="170px" />
      <div id="janela" class="container" class="container2" class="container3">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TEFvChC.png" />
        <div id="intro-j" class="container">text</div>
        <div id="circo-gif-j" class="container">
          <img src="https://www.gif.ovh/portuguese-gif/Palha%C3%A7o%20Gif/Palha%C3%A7o%20Gif%20(21).gif" />
        </div>
        <div id="menu" class="container">
          <b><a href="cartas.php" id="lc">• Cartas</a><br />• Contato</b>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="lona" class="container" class="container2">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZHX8oEe.png" height="700px" />
        <div id="counter" class="container" class="container2" class="container3">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/pGkiIuH.png" height="200px" width="850px" />
          <div id="bem-vindo" class="container">
            <img src="https://gifimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/seja-bem-vindo-gif-6.gif" />
            <div id="balao" class="container">
              <a href="javascript:alert('---');"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/pcJDYM7.gif" height="90px" /></a>
            </div>

            <div id="logoblog" class="container">
              <a href=""><img src="https://i.imgur.com/CLC5YzA.gif" /></a>

              <!--GAIOLA-->
              <div id="gaiola" class="container">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/zlmgazC.gif" /></a>
              </div>

              <!--BOLO-->
              <div id="bolo" class="container">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/RjoYsYb.gif" height="90px" /></a>
              </div>

              <!--COMPUTADOR-->
              <div id="computador" class="container">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/s4sHQ1V.gif" height="200px" /></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal 1 - GAIOLA-->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="modal-text">modal text 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal 2 - Computador-->
  <div id="modal2" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="modal-text">modal text 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal 3 - Computador-->
  <div id="modal3" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="modal-text">modal text 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
```

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
}

.container2 {
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
}

.container3 {
  position: relative;
}

#intro-j {
  position: fixed;
  top: 196px;
  left: 44px;
  color: #ffff00;
}

#balao {
  position: fixed;
  top: 370px;
  left: 966px;
}

#bem-vindo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 423px;
}

#logoblog {
  position: fixed;
  top: -2px;
  left: 51px;
}

#gaiola {
  position: fixed;
  top: 450px;
  left: 330px;
}

#lona {
  position: fixed;
  left: 248px;
  top: 15px;
}

#counter {
  position: fixed;
  top: 540px;
  left: 170px;
}

#janela {
  position: fixed;
  top: 170px;
  left: 15px;
}

#circo-gif-j {
  position: fixed;
  top: 370px;
  left: 47px;
}

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 550px;
  left: 44px;
  color: #00ff00;
}

#lc {
  color: #00ff00;
}

#mesabolo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 540px;
  left: 960px;
}

#bolo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 470px;
  left: 1018px;
}

#computador {
  position: fixed;
  top: 394px;
  left: 700px;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ffe38a;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

#modal-text {
  color: #c83434;
}

.visible {
  display: block !important;
  z-index: 3;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  /* Sit on top of the page content */
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  /* Black background with opacity */
  z-index: 2;
  /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different order for other elements */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Add a pointer on hover */
}
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FF6842">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0uGRDgL.png" alt="Cortinas" height="600px" width="1250px" id="bg" />
        <div id="mesabolo" class="container" class="container2" class="container3">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MKP2Ezx.png" height="170px" />
            <div id="janela" class="container" class="container2" class="container3">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TEFvChC.png" />
                <div id="intro-j" class="container">text</div>
                <div id="circo-gif-j" class="container">
                    <img src="https://www.gif.ovh/portuguese-gif/Palha%C3%A7o%20Gif/Palha%C3%A7o%20Gif%20(21).gif" />
                </div>
                <div id="menu" class="container">
                    <b><a href="cartas.php" id="lc">• Cartas</a><br />• Contato</b>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="lona" class="container" class="container2">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZHX8oEe.png" height="700px" />
                <div id="counter" class="container" class="container2" class="container3">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/pGkiIuH.png" height="200px" width="850px" />
                    <div id="bem-vindo" class="container">
                        <img src="https://gifimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/seja-bem-vindo-gif-6.gif" />
                        <div id="balao" class="container">
                            <a href="javascript:alert('---');"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/pcJDYM7.gif"
                                    height="90px" /></a>
                        </div>

                        <div id="logoblog" class="container">
                            <a href=""><img src="https://i.imgur.com/CLC5YzA.gif" /></a>

                            <!--GAIOLA-->
                            <div id="gaiola" class="container">
                                <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/zlmgazC.gif" /></a>
                            </div>

                            <!--BOLO-->
                            <div id="bolo" class="container">
                                <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/RjoYsYb.gif" height="90px" /></a>
                            </div>

                            <!--COMPUTADOR-->
                            <div id="computador" class="container">
                                <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/s4sHQ1V.gif" height="200px" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal 1 - GAIOLA-->
    <div id="modal1" class="modal">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="modal-text">modal text 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal 2 - Computador-->
    <div id="modal2" class="modal">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="modal-text">modal text 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal 3 - Computador-->
    <div id="modal3" class="modal">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="modal-text">modal text 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <!--Scripts start-->
    <script>
        //Array with a list of the modal id and conatiner id
        var modalsArray = [
            ["modal1", "gaiola"],
            ["modal2", "bolo"],
            ["modal3", "computador"],
        ];
        //stores the currently visible modal
        var visibleModal;
        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            if (e.target == visibleModal) {
                visibleModal.classList.remove("visible");
                visibleModal = "";
                document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
            }
        });

        //Iterate through the modalsArray and add a click event listener
        for (let modal = 0; modal < modalsArray.length; modal++) {
            document
                .getElementById(modalsArray[modal][1])
                .addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    for (let mod = 0; mod < modalsArray.length; mod++) {
                        if (
                            e.target.offsetParent ==
                            document.getElementById(modalsArray[mod][1])
                        ) {
                            //add the visible class to show the modal
                            document
                                .getElementById(modalsArray[mod][0])
                                .classList.add("visible");
                            //store the currently visible modal in the visible modal variable
                            visibleModal = document.getElementById(modalsArray[mod][0]);
                            // stops the click event from propagating up which would hide the modal again
                            document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
                            e.stopPropagation();
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you very very much, this is exactly what I needed! Very thankful that you basically rewrote the entire modal part lol! Works perfectly now and made it all more simple and practical, it's definitely gonna speed up my workflow for this project!